# Rewriting a recurrence in another form

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I have the following recurrence:

$$T(n) = n^{\log_2(k)/\log_2(n)} T(n/2) + n$$

I've tried to rewrite $n^{log_2(k)/log_2(n)}$ in another form but I don't see another way except $\sqrt[\log_2(n)]{...}$. Does anyone see a clever format to that?

Comment: In general, if you have $n^{\log_b\dots}$ it helps to write it as $(b^{\log_b n})^{\log_b\dots} = b^{\log_b n \log_b\dots}$ and see where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I've tried to rewrite `n^{log_2(k)/log_2(n)}` in another form but I don't see another way except `square root of degree log_2(n)`. Does anyone see a clever format to that?*

One may observe that
$$
n^{\log_2(k)/\log_2(n)}=n^{\log(k)/\log(n)}=e^{\frac{\log(k)}{\log(n)} \cdot \log (n)}=k.
$$

Comment: @Mike M. You are welcome.